# React native navigation v5 navigate tab inside bottomBar

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

I have built an application that has a "list mode" and an "item mode". In list mode, you have a list of, well, "items". And when you select an item you navigate inside a detail view that has a bottom bar with tabs (@react-navigation/bottom-tabs).

[image: navigation diagram]

Now, when I'm on the list mode, with react-navigation v4 I was able to navigate inside the list landing in a particular tab, but I don't understand how to do this using react-navigation v5.

I have basically this structure

```
<NavigationContainer>
  <Stack.Navigator headerMode="none">
    <Stack.Screen name="List" component={ItemsScreen} />

    <Stack.Screen name="Item" component={MainTabNavigator} />
  </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>;
```

I can easily navigate

```
<Stack.Screen name="ItemDetail" component={ItemDetailScreen} />;
```

But, if I do that, I navigate it inside the main view and not inside the bottom bar.

Any ideas on how I could move the app on the item mode with the second tab selected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify the screen when navigating like below

Here 'tabs' is the screen in the stack which holds the tab navigator and 'Settings' is the screen in the tab.
This will navigate to tabs screen and switch to Settings tab.

```
<Button title="Navigate" onPress={()=>navigation.navigate('tabs',{screen:'Settings'})}/>
```